# What legal remedies exist when a computer game crashes a computer?

Tags: contract-law, software, warranties

If a company sells a video game that consistently crashes computers with a certain type of graphics card, does the law allow a consumer to force the game maker to patch the error or otherwise correct the problem?

Comment: Did the software guarantee that it will work correctly with the particular hardware and OS?

Comment: You won't be able to force them to patch the game, any remedy (if they didn't want to patch it) would probably be limited to the amount you paid for the game. This information is probably in the license that was provided when you installed it (and probably skipped and hit "Accept" without reading like most people do, myself included).

Comment: The answer depends on the jurisdiction. Where do you live? Where did you purchase the game? 
I'm not aware of any UK or EU law that forces software makers to patch software but I am aware of laws that provide for a right to "repair or replacement" in cases of "digital content" (defined in EU and UK law) where it is not "of a satisfactory quality", "fit for a particular purpose" or "in compliance with description". This might be reduced pro rata for the time that you enjoyed the game.

Comment: It's Germany, and the Hardware fits the minimum That is mentioned, I even played it once with even lower hardware, because I had a defect and was waiting for the new ordered GPU, but my hardware plus drivers are OK, even my Sellftest tools and a paid Computer Spec told me that it's definitely not the Hardware, he also checked my Windows, he didn't find any mistakes, (Well, he found mistakes, But these are bugs that came with the update he's said)

Comment: Besides, thank you for simplifieing and reading ;), Simplifieing text isn't exactly my strength

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a jurisdiction and comments address several other jurisdictions. I will consider the question in light of U.S. law.

In the U.S., any right you might have related to this kind of problem is almost always expressly waived by contract in a "shrink wrap agreement" that can't be severed from the computer game, and U.S. law generally upholds this contractual limitation of your warranty rights pursuant to federal law related to "limited warranties".

If the purchase was made with a credit card, often the credit card would allow you to cancel the charge if the product is unsatisfactory, and in practice, many companies that limit their warranties so as to disallow all relief will actually be willing to give you a refund if that kind of problem comes up.

Answer (score 0):

In the EU, you can get your money back, since the product is of unsatisfactory quality. (It's a bit interesting, because the identical product is of satisfactory quality to most customers). I don't think you have any rights to get the problem fixed, because most likely the cost of fixing it is much much higher than the cost of the game.

PS. Obviously the crash can also be caused by a fault in your graphics card or the software for your graphics card. So it's unlikely that you don't get your money back, because that's the easiest way for the company to get rid of you and your complaint, but if you tried to demand something that costs the company money, they will ask you to prove that it's their game that is defective and not your graphics card. Good luck.